# How can I make a decorator that checks if the form(any custom form) is submitted or not in django?

Tags: python, django

I am making a webpage like food ordering in restaurant. So I have included a form in which customer must have to fill the form which includes Name, Table number, Password, etc to order the food. For that I want to make a decorator so that customer can not directly go to another page directly without filling the form.

```
from django import forms
from order.models import LoginModel
from django.core import validators
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator
def check_password(value):
    if value != 'onetofour':
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Password")
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    Table_number = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(4)])
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput,validators[check_password,])
    class Meta:
        model = LoginModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view where your form is getting submitted, you can access session and set `form_submitted` to `True` like

```
request.session['form_submitted'] = True
```

and then create a decorator like

```
def check_form_submitted(func):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.get('form_submitted'):
            # raise 404 ?
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

and add this decorator to views where you have to validate if user has submitted the form.